# In react-devtools, what do the various highlighting colors of the "highlightUpdates" option mean

Tags: react-devtools

I've been using the react-devtools to detect any unnecessary component updates, however I'm not sure I fully understand how it works.

I can identify the various components that got updated by the added borders indicating that they got updated but I'm not sure what the various colors of those borders mean (I've so far seen cyan and light green colors).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this either, but I'll trace through the code! :)

[This is the component that renders the "Highlight Updates" toggle.](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/4d3ae51dc31617bd813339fb7baa00e0154a0023/plugins/TraceUpdates/TraceUpdatesFrontendControl.js#L21-L27) It calls a [`changeTraceUpdates` method in the main `Store`](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/4d3ae51dc31617bd813339fb7baa00e0154a0023/frontend/Store.js#L551-L556) which sends a message through the "bridge" to [activate the `TraceUpdatesBackendManager`](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/4d3ae51dc31617bd813339fb7baa00e0154a0023/plugins/TraceUpdates/TraceUpdatesBackendManager.js#L85-L88). Poking around that file, we see a couple of classes with names like "presenter" in them; I assume one of these is what actually draws the border. In particular, [`TraceUpdatesWebNodePresenter` looks related because it defines an array of `COLORS`](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/4d3ae51dc31617bd813339fb7baa00e0154a0023/plugins/TraceUpdates/TraceUpdatesWebNodePresenter.js#L20-L30). It looks like these colors are chosen based on a "hit" attribute, which a quick search suggests is [set by `TraceUpdatesAbstractNodePresenter`– and gets incremented each time an element is "presented"](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/4d3ae51dc31617bd813339fb7baa00e0154a0023/plugins/TraceUpdates/TraceUpdatesAbstractNodePresenter.js#L64-L67).

Reading between the lines then, I assume this means that components that render less frequently will be outlined with "cool" colors (blue) and ones that render more frequently will be outlined with "hot" colors (red).

Comment: You are awesome Brian! Sorry for mentioning explicitly on the tweet, did it because (I falsely thought that) you are one of the main contributors of react-devtools.

Comment: No problem! I am one of the main contributors at this point. I've just never worked with that particular feature. 